# Is is prefered to have the Pasach meal on the first or second night?

Tags: passover, calendar, passover-seder-hagada

I remember being told that the Seder can be on either the first or second night. Is this true, and if so, is it prefered for it to take place on one over the other, or are they both equal?

Edit:

The tag here says the first night or two, but the main question still stands: is one prefered?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Israel, only the first night is a full holiday, and as such, the Seder is only ever on the first night.

In the Diaspora, both the first and second nights are full holidays. The Seder should be done on both nights.

If, for some reason, someone is really only able to do one of them, it should be the first. This is because the first night is a Biblical holiday, while the second night is only a Rabbinic enactment.

Comment: While I don't doubt the truth of your last paragraph, do you have a source for it?

Comment: Common sense. I just know the principle that a Biblical commandment takes precedence over a Rabbinic one.

Comment: Hm..... [15 char]

Comment: Is that 2 meals over the nights or the whole Seder over the 2?

Comment: @Tim Two whole sederim, one each night.

Comment: @Shokhet Also, you don't pass up an opportunity.